# C++ std::sort() - Unable to sort a vector of a class type that access member variables

Tags: c++, function, class, sorting, std

`Entry.h`:

```
//returns the sum of all non mega entry percentages
float sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(vector<Number>& arg1_Numbers);
```

`Entry.cpp`:

```
//returns the sum of all mega entry percentages
float Entry::sumOfMegaEntryPct(vector<MegaNumber>& arg1_MegaNumbers)
{
    float sumPct = 0.00f;
     for (MegaNumber c : megaEntry)
     {
         sumPct = sumPct + arg1_MegaNumbers[c.getID()].getOccurencePct();
     }

     return sumPct;
}
```

`Lotto.h`:

```
public:
//compares two entries, used for sorting algorithm, sorts by nonmega number
bool compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(Entry arg1, Entry arg2); 

    protected:
    vector<Numbers> numbers;
    vector<MegaNumbers> megaNumbers;
```

`Lotto.cpp`:

```
#include "lotto.h"

//sorts nonmega numbers by sum of their pct, used for sort algorithm
bool Lotto::compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(Entry arg1, Entry arg2)
{
    bool b = arg1.sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(numbers) < arg2.sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(numbers);
     return b;
}
```

`Source.cpp`:

```
vector<Entry> copyGameEntry = game.getPlayEntry();
sort(copyGameEntry.begin(), copyGameEntry.end(),
     bind(&Lotto::compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega, game));
```

This is just a part of the code, but I think it's enough to make sense. When compiling, I get the error(s):

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  C2451   conditional
>   expression of type 'std::_Unforced' is illegal    Lottery Sort    e:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm 3133
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  C2675   unary '!':
>   'std::_Unforced' does not define this operator or a conversion to a
>   type acceptable to the predefined operator    Lottery Sort    e:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm 3118

Question:

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Post a code that almost compiles...You think `class Lottery {` ... `};` is not relevant? `sumOfNonMegaEntryPct` is not declared as a member function. What isn't important is how you divide code between .h and .cpp files, you can define member functions in the class definition itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `std::bind` incorrectly. You need to use placeholders for the unbound arguments:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
sort(copyGameEntry.begin(), copyGameEntry.end(),
     bind(&Lotto::compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega, game, _1, _2));
```

N.B. this bind expression will copy the `game` object, so you should either use `std::ref(game)` or just `&game` instead, to avoid an unnecessary copy.

Or use a lambda function:

```
sort(copyGameEntry.begin(), copyGameEntry.end(),
     [&game](Entry& l, Entry& r) {
       return game.compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega(l, r);
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

There are alternatives to invoke std::sort:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct X
{
    int value;
    bool operator < (const X& other) const { return value < other.value; }
    static bool less(const X& a, const X& b) { return a.value < b.value; }
};

struct Holder
{
    bool less(const X& a, const X& b) const { return a.value < b.value; }
};

int main ()
{
    Holder holder;
    std::vector<X> values;

    // No stateful comparison
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());

    // No stateful comparison
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), X::less);

    // Stateful comparison
    struct Less {
        const Holder& holder;
        Less(const Holder& holder) : holder(holder) {}
        bool operator ()(const X& a, const X& b) const { return holder.less(a, b); }
    };
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), Less(holder));

    // Stateful comparison
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), [&holder](const X& a, const X& b) {
        return holder.less(a, b);
    });

    // Stateful comparison
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), std::bind(&Holder::less, holder, _1, _2));
}
```

Likely, in your case you are missing std::placeholders

Comment: Only the last line (which is correct) is useful. The other examples are not relevant, because they don't show how to use a stateful comparison function (it must be stateful because it needs to refer to the `numbers` member of the `Lotto` object).

Answer (score -1):

**Your error** is related to: `bind(&Lotto::compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega, game)`.

You need to specify [std::placeholders](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/placeholders/) when you call function [std::bind](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/), which will be replaced by the arguments of the called, returned function object, in the specified order.

You could verify using the following `try - catch` block:

```
try {
    std::sort(copyGameEntry.begin(), copyGameEntry.end(),
              bind(&Lotto::compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega, game)

} catch (std::bad_function_call& e) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: Bad function call\n";

}
```

In your case you need to add:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto func_obj = bind(&Lotto::compareEntry_sumPct_nonMega, game, _1, _2);
```

then, the `func_obj (_1, _2)` will be called, internally by `sort()`, as:

```
func_obj(copyGameEntry[i], copyGameEntry[i+1]);
```

**Alternatively**, you can try using something like:

```
struct Holder{
    bool less(const Entry& a, const Entry& b) const { 
        return a.sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(numbers) < b.sumOfNonMegaEntryPct(numbers); 
    }
} holder;

struct Less {
    const Holder& holder;
    Less(const Holder& holder) : holder(holder) {}
    bool operator ()(const Entry& a, const Entry& b) const { return holder.less(a, b); }
};

std::sort(copyGameEntry.begin(), copyGameEntry.end(), Less(holder));
```